# PXE booting server in VirtualBox network configuration

Tags: virtualbox, rhel6, pxe-boot

I have a host machine(windows) which has a rhel6 guest running in virtual box. I want to boot my laptop through PXE server configured in this guest machine. 
I have configured all the necessary servers for pxe boot in the rhel guest but unable to figure out how will the laptop get the IP from the dhcp server running in rhel. The adapter should be in Bridged or NAT mode ??
I can ping the host from the guest but I have no idea how will my laptop (connected physically to the windows machine),will be able to communicate with the virtual machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best/easy way is to switch it in bridge mode so both DHCP request broadcast and TFTP requests can reach the virtual server.

Comment: Just to clarify, this will not work at all unless you use Bridge mode.

Comment: In some complicated situations - it will. This is simple desktop case.

Comment: This is whta my dhcpd.conf looks like :
`subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
 option routers 192.168.0.254;
 option domain-name-servers 192.168.0.254;
 option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
 range dynamic-bootp 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.10;
 filename "/pxelinux.0";
 next-server 192.168.0.254;
 } `
do I necessarily  have to aasign a static IP to my rhel machine(which is in bridged mode), and will my host network card abel to get the IP from the guests dhcp server ??

Comment: this is dhcpd configuration, do you need some help?

Comment: Yes, it must be static, otherwise you have to change dhcpd configuration on every new ip address assigned to the server